# Modify bash history from inside subshell in an interactive session

Tags: bash, history

I executed

```
history > before; (history -d $n); history > after
```

where `$n` is the number corresponding to the last command I typed in the same interactive session before executing this line,

The result is that the line marked `$n` is not removed from history. If I remove the parentheses so that the `history -d` runs in the current shell, it works as documented.

How to understand this behavior? Is it true that all scripts that manipulate history need to be `source`d?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each shell process has its own idea of what the command-line history is. When an interactive shell exits it will write its remembered history to `~/.bash_history` for the next shell to pick up, but that's the extent of cooperation between shell processes.

In your command, the `()` makes the shell fork a copy of itself to run `history -d` command. The child process starts out with a copy of the parent's internal state, so it knows the history, and is able to make changes to *its* copy of it.

However, when the subshell exits, its copy of the history (which was just rewritten) is discarded together with the rest of its internal state). The subshell knows it is a subshell, so it doesn't even bother to write `~/.bash_history`.

---

A script that is not sourced usually cannot manipulate history at all, because it is interpreted by a fresh *non-interactive* shell that doesn't even read `~/.bash_history` at startup.

You *can* get the shell to behave like an interactive shell by specifying it on the command line:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
echo something
```

The shell that runs this script will append its commands (which includes both the shebang line and the `echo something`) to the `~/.bash_history` it finds on disk. But of course that doesn't affect the in-memory history copy of the shell process you *invoke* the script from, and when it exits the changes the script made to `~/.bash_history` will be lost anyway.

Comment: Great answer. It would be better if some reference to manual pages or other documents are included.